# Split string into Dictionary key and Value

Tags: c#, json, dictionary

I am trying to split a response (string) received from a camera into keys and values. This is what the string from IP camera look like:

```
{"error":0,"session":678939290,"group":131071}
```

I want to Split them into keys and arrays without the "".
For ecample:

**Keys** <---- >**Values**

**error** *0*

**session** *678939290*

**group** *131071*

Below is the code I currently use:

```
string tempResponse = serverResponse;


        //Remove Left and Right curly braces
        tempResponse = tempResponse.Replace("{", "");
        tempResponse = tempResponse.Replace("}", "");

        //Remove '"' from the string
        tempResponse = tempResponse.Replace("\"", "");

        //Now Make sure that there is no Space begining and end of the string
        tempResponse = tempResponse.TrimStart().TrimEnd();


        var items = tempResponse.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.None)
    .Select(s => s.Split(new[] { ':' }));

        Dictionary<string, string> camInfoDICT = null; //Stores the camInfo as keys and values
        camInfoDICT = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var item in items)
        {
            try
            {
                camInfoDICT.Add(item[0], item[1]);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Debug.Log("Exception " + e.Message);
            }
        }
```

**It works**. The code **functions** as expected and I was able to **extract** the information from `camInfoDICT` as **Keys** and **Values**.

The **problem** is that it is **throwing** an `Exception` of `Exception Array index is out of range`. in

```
 foreach (var item in items)
            {
                try
                {
                    camInfoDICT.Add(item[0], item[1]);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Exception " + e.Message);
                }
            }
```

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of doing *manual* parsing, use Json convert. The string is a [JSON string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). You can use any available JSON deserializers, for example with [Newtonsoft JSON parser](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/) it would be:

```
string jsonString = "{\"error\":0,\"session\":678939290,\"group\":131071}";
Dictionary<string, int> camInfoDICT = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(jsonString);
```

To include Netwonsoft JSON, use Nugget Package Manager in Visual Studio.